# Invalid postback or callback argument error when click delete button which using OnItemCommand in a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Whenever using click the delete button, it shows Invalid postback or callback argument error**

**Aims: To delete the specific Product_ID in the datalist**

Below is the Aspx and Aspx.cs codes

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="100%" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <br />
                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" CssClass="prodImage" Height="100px" Length="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("product_image") %>' />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pid") %>' />
                            <h4><small><%# Eval("product_des") %></small></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
                                <h4><strong><%# Eval("Price","{0:c}") %><span class="text-muted"></span></strong></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <script>
                                    function validateInput(event) {
                                        // Get the value entered by the user
                                        var input = event.target.value;

                                        // Validate if the input is a valid number
                                        if (isNaN(input) || parseFloat(input) < 1) {
                                            event.target.value = ''; // Clear the input
                                            alert('Please enter a valid number greater than or equal to 1.');
                                        }
                                    }
                                </script>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" onkeyup="validateInput(event)" value="<%# Eval("Quantity") %>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">
                                <asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" BackColor="Red" CommandName="DeleteItem" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Pid") %>'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteItem")
        {
            // Get the unique ID of the item to delete from the CommandArgument
            string itemID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Write(itemID.ToString());
            DeleteProductFromCart(itemID.ToString());
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private void DeleteProductFromCart(string itemID)
    {
        // Replace this with your actual database operation to delete the product from the cart
        string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        conn.Open();
        string sqlQuery2 = "DELETE FROM Orders WHERE Pid=@Pid";
        SqlCommand comm2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, conn);
        comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pid", itemID);
        comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Still learning on the OnItemCommand features. Any suggestions and opinions are appreciated. Thank you